# How to resize a background image to fit an asp table exactly?

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating an ASP.NET web application and would like to show text on top of images in a table. Since I have not been able to include both text and an image control in a TableCell, I have nested a table within each cell and set the image as the background of the table, before writing text within it. However, the background image does not always fit the cell because the table is automatically resized when the page loads.

How can I set the background image to exactly fill the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this using css:

```
td table {
    background: url(path/to/background.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sjkm, this worked although it turned out I needed to use background-size: cover. Also, I needed CSS 3.0.